# How To Use BigQuery Standard SQL UDF?

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries

I refer to the BigQuery Standard SQL UDF Document

But I still do not know how to include js include BigQuery

I have tried to add js lib source in Options

But got this error
Error: Not Implemented: UDFs are currently only supported for legacy SQL queries.

我參考了BigQuery Standard SQL UDF Document

但我還是不了解該如何將js include至BigQuery中

我有試著在Options新增js lib source

但是得到了這個錯誤
Error: Not Implemented: UDFs are currently only supported for legacy SQL queries.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Using images as references to the code are not welcomed here and will not help answering your question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure not to include any text in the "UDF Editor" pane, which is specific to legacy SQL. Instead, the `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` statements should be in the `Query Editor` pane. See also the [topic in the migration guide on differences in user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_user-defined_javascript_functions).